# Sinatra, retrieve only post parameters

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I know I can retrieve every parameter in Sinatra using "params".
However, How can I retrieve only post parameters? I need to verify that a parameter was sent by POST, otherwise it should be ignored.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing the request object directly gives you a simple way of accessing post data, much like the php $_POST variable:

```
post '/' do
  request.POST.inspect # instead of params.inspect
end
```

More info on the Rack request object here: http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html#M000274